# How to style AG-GRID column vertical borders

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I want my AG-Grid columns to have vertical borders. By default the grid rows have horizontal borders. I want it to mimic the regular Excel spreadsheet look and feel.

I have tried using cell-styling in the column definitions like so:

```
this.columnDefs = [
  { headerName: 'Test', cellStyle: {'border-right-color': '#e2e2e2'}, field: 'test' }];
```

This does the trick. But when I click on a cell to edit, the blue border it puts on the active cell is overwritten by the cellstyling above, so i get a cell with 3 blue borders and 1 grey border.

This can't be the correct approach for this....

Has anybody any ideas? I've attempted to do some CSS styling, but have gotten nowhere as it seems to be insanely difficult to figure out which classes to overwrite.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

it is better done by styling the ag-grid theme. Here are docs about it https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-themes-customising/

And I made a simple Stackblitz with borders [Borders Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-cell-border?file=src%2Fstyles.scss) that you can check out.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: The stackblitz link is now has a runtime error
Error in src/styles.scss
NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'write$1' on null

Comment: @EdSpencer - I just noticed that too. Albeit I did see the example load... it was only after a pause (a few seconds at most) that the table was hidden and I saw the error. I thought I'd look for a fix but from my fairly brief investigation this is a known issue in StackBlitz: https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/issues/25 and being wokred on

Comment: stackblitz broken

Answer (score 5):

```
.ag-theme-alpine {
  --ag-cell-horizontal-border: var(--ag-row-border-width)
    var(--ag-row-border-style) var(--ag-row-border-color); /* Add left and right borders to each cell and use row border's properties  */
  --ag-header-column-separator-display: block;
}
```

[ag-grid reference css variables](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/global-style-customisation-variables/#reference-variables---ag-cell-horizontal-border)

Comment: For specifying the border-width, we need to add the '    --ag-row-border-width' css property separately, as mentioned in the above link.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me! Thanks