# How to set a border on a single column in ag-grid

Tags: css, angular, sass, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have a table whose first n columns are different in some way to the remaining m columns. I want to use a vertical border on the right side of the nth column (in both header and rows) to highlight the distinction.

We use Balham theme with the columnDefs defined in component.ts, and component.html containing:

```
<ag-grid-angular
  class="ag-theme-balham"
  [rowData]="vm.data$ | async"
  [columnDefs]="columnsDefs$ | async"
  [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
  [columnTypes]="columnTypes"
>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

In [How to style AG-GRID column vertical borders](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62371529) a suggestion was made to use theme customisation but I don't want borders on all columns, just one. Even using `cellStyle: { 'border-right-colour': 'black' }` within the relevant columnDef doesn't render anything because it is being overriden by Balham's transparent border.

How can I locate a particular column in the table and selectively style it differently to the rest?

Answer (score 3):

You can add a `headerClass` and `cellClass` on the columns you want to have borders on. For example, you can add the same class on the column:

```
    {
      field: 'age',
      headerClass: ['age-border'],
      maxWidth: 90,
      cellClass: ['age-border'],
    },
```

```
.age-border {
  border-right: 3px solid red !important;
  border-left: 3px solid red !important
}
```

See this implemented in the [following sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/RAkzoxqNlm0bmErY?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts)